# How to fix aws console problem (every code became oneline)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I closed my AWS console after the session ended.
And I reopened it and found every file in every directory became one line like below.
I think this is about a format setting problem or something.
How can I fix it

{"filter":false,"title":"guess.feature","tooltip":"/work/hw-sinatra-saas-hangperson/features/guess.feature","undoManager":{"mark":-1,"position":-1,"stack":[]},"ace":{"folds":[],"scrolltop":0,"scrollleft":0,"selection":{"start":{"row":15,"column":18},"end":{"row":15,"column":18},"isBackwards":false},"options":{"guessTabSize":true,"useWrapMode":false,"wrapToView":true},"firstLineState":0},"timestamp":1556672503420,"hash":"7c932328fb87b63ff3d5362a56f39ca0bd38857a"}

Comment: is versioning (for your s3) turned on?

Answer (score 1):

The format of the text you've put above is known as JSON. It looks like your JSON has been consolidated to a one liner. There are plenty of free tools to format your JSON, infact most IDE's come with the feature to do it (and if not, there's always a plugin for it!). For now, you can use an online formatter: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
Just remember to use the copy button and not try copy paste it yourself to avoid ruining the format due to the collapse/expand buttons.